# ext.net store Clear Filter problems in combobox

Tags: c#, wcf, ext.net

Case 1 (working fine)

1. Open the page
2. Select a value from the `combobox1`
3. Select other value from the `combobox2`
4. Click New record

Case 2 (issue)

1. Open the page, write some word for filter the `combobox1` for
   example "H"
2. Select other value from the `combobox2` filter word
   "B"
3. Click New record
4. `combobox1` - just showing which values
   starting "H"
5. `combobox2` - just showing which values starting "B" Code;

**aspx**

```
<ext:ComboBox ID="combobox1 " runat="server" DisplayField="CountyName" ValueField="ISSCode" QueryMode="Local">
<Store> <ext:Store ID="str1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true">
```

**aspx.cs**

Before databind I used `clearfilter()`

```
str1.ClearFilter();
str1.DataSource = countyDataTable;
str1.DataBind();
```

Comment: combobox1 .GetStore().ClearFilter()

Comment: please try this

Comment: thank you @ChetanSanghani but it doesnt working. when i used "GetStoe().ClearFilter()" this time if i want change my value from combobox1 it is showing me same oldValue and if i click NewRecord this time combobox doesnt filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution

```
combobox1.Reset();
strCounties.DataSource = countyDataTable;
strCounties.DataBind();
```